# Как динамически изменить картинку?

Tags: android

У меня картинка с шириной Match_Parent и высотой 160dp а внизу всякие тексты. На 4-дюймовом нормально смотрится! Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при больших экранах, например если больше 5 дюймового экрана то картинка тоже увеличивалась при этом без потери пропорции!

Comment: а зачем так делать? можно с помощью `Drawable Importer`-a сгенерить под все размеры экранов и все

Comment: Не понял если честно.

Comment: То есть на все эти папки кинуть разные размеры картинки?

Comment: ну да, программно менять размер это немного на велосипед смахивает) зачем так сложно?

Comment: не спорю, такой вариант возможен, если картинка находится где-то на сервере и ее нужно программно скачивать и подставлять в `layout` какой-нибудь

Comment: но если картинку можно положить в папку с проектом, то проще с помощью плагина сгенерить под нужные размеры и все

Comment: Мне просто нужно сделать так... Если дюйм телефона <= 4, то высота картинки = 160dp, иначе высота картинки = 180dp! Импортер думаешь сможет сделать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34763/discussion-between--and-omuradil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описывал раньше как [ResizableImageView](http://suvitruf.ru/2013/12/17/3426/) сделать:

```
public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {

    public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
         Drawable d = getDrawable();

         if(d!=null){
                 int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                 int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
                 setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
         }else{
                 super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
         }
    }

}
```

Изображение будет занимать всю ширину контейнера, а затем подгонит высоту под нужные пропорции.

Вместо обычного `ImageView`, делать так в разметке:

```
 <ru.your.package.ResizableImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ivHeader" />
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую...

Comment: А куда мою картинку прописать ID картинки к примеру ivHeader?

Comment: @Omuradil `<ru.your.package.ResizableImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ivHeader" />`

Comment: У меня вместо картинки серый фон! В чем проблема? конечно свой пакет прописал!

Comment: Короче @drawable/ivHeader прописал не в src а в Background, как думаешь правильно ли это?

Comment: @Omuradil если работает, то да.

Comment: Можно ещё использовать аттрибут [`android:adjustViewBounds`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds). Он как раз для того что бы изображение сохраняло оригинальный аспект. Только он не при всех `scaleType` работает и вроде только с API 18 всё корректно.